# Error confirmación de dirección/correo enviado

Tags: web, formularios, script, mail, formdata

Hola estoy perdido y no le encuentro el fallo.
En una página de la web tengo un formulario para que el lector meta su dirección de correo y pulse el botón a enviar. Lo único que necesito es que me llegue a mi correo la confirmación que esta persona a puesto su correo de identificación, para yo saber que está interesada.
La cuestión es que a mi correo personal no me llega ninguna notificación.
Donde está el error?

````
        <button class="button-send" id="send-button">
            <span class="button-text">
                ENVIAR
            </span>
        </button>
        <span class="input-description" style="display: none;" id="text-confirm">
            Gracias. Enseguida nos pondremos en contacto con usted.
        </span>
        <script>
            var sendButton = document.getElementById("send-button");
            sendButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                var input = document.getElementById("email");
                var value = input.value;
                if (value != "") {
                    const form = new FormData();
                    form.append('from', value);
                    form.append('to', 'joselm65@gmail.com');
                    form.append('subject', `${userName} está interesado en GPT Care`);
                    form.append('text', `${userName} con email ${value} está interesado en GPT Care`);

                    fetch('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox5759acc5026845d88c92b60e1045d717.mailgun.org/messages', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('api:9c422337978d994def393a88ba9ab619-181449aa-822aa8ea')
                    },
                    body: form
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        input.value = "";
                        const text = document.getElementById("text-confirm");
                        text.style.display = "block";
                    });
                }
            });
        </script> ```
````